# Riyadh transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, us-citizens, saudi-arabia, ruh

I'm a US citizen, flying on two separate tickets - one-ways in and out of Riyadh. They are:

- Saudi Air (HYD—RUH) inbound with a 2 hr 25 min layover, claiming bags and re-checking to
- Whizz Malta Air RHU-FCO.

I know I will need a transit/stopover visa but cannot get it online
with Saudi Air my inbound carrier because I'm on a one way. I think the visa has to be done on the MOFA website, which is very user unfriendly IMHO and I have spent hours trying to decipher.

I plan to book with KIWI.com but would have the same issue as booking with Saudi Air, since it's a one-way with them. Does anyone have any recent experience for how long immigration and customs lines are in Terminal 4? I have 2 hr and 25 min to claim bags, etc and present myself at the Wizz Air counter in Terminal 3. I arrive at Terminal 4 at 6 PM on Friday January 12.

Comment: Your layover time is short and the ticket seller gives no protection in case of delays. Even the shortest delay can cause you to miss the connection.

Comment: You _really_ wanna have your ducks in a row with this short layover, down to knowing exactly where you need to go or how to figure it out quickly. You may not even have time for a potty break.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474/!ut/p/z0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivQIsTAwdDQz9LQwNzQwCnS0tXPwMvYwN3A30g1Pz9L30o_ArAppiVOTr7JuuH1WQWJKhm5mXlq8fYWFibqJfkO0eDgDtRK6y/) from the Saudi Arabia Ministry of Foreign Affairs describes the process for a non-Saudi citizen to apply online for a SA transit visa.

The process has multiple steps, but each step seems straightforward: login, choose "individuals," choose "Application from Saudi Missions Abroad," "Register," agree to "Terms and Conditions," provide photograph, select "Transit Visa" as visa type," and fill in required information.

Note that the visa charge (in the above page's right-hand column) is 300.0 SAR, or about US$80.

Comment: Many thx David !-  yes having trouble with the registration - they have a tech support number but have not been able to get through -  Much appreciated !